# Summation of a field in specified date range

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-date-functions

I need help with the following -- please help .

[image: Sample Image]

How to summate a date range.?? I am a newbie in Oracle .

Comment: On what basis the grouping is done?

Comment: based on a date range -for example I want to make 2 separate groups GR1 and GR2 where GR1 will be (01-Feb-13 to 04-Feb-13)  and 
GR2 will be  (03-Feb-13 to 07-Feb-13) . Please let me know if it's clear enough .

Comment: So your date ranges are *hard-coded* ?

Comment: Also, how do you derive Field4 in the output?

Comment: Field 4 is just the summation of the values in the dates of GR1 and GR2 . for example the first row in the example - Field-4 is the summation of values in the date range 01-Feb to 04-Feb .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, TRUNC(MIN(FIELD3)), TRUNC(MAX(FIELD3)), SUM(FIELD4)
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE FIELD3 BETWEEN DATE '2013-02-01'
                   AND DATE '2013-02-04' + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
  GROUP BY FIELD1, FIELD2
  ORDER BY MIN(FIELD3);
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Using hard-coded dates is a bit odd, as is the way you're making your ranges (and your `field4` value appears to be wrong in your sample output), but assuming you know what you want...

You can use a`case` statement to assign a dummy group number to the rows based on the dates, and then have an outer query that uses `group by` against that dummy field, which I've called `gr`:

```
select field1, field2,
    to_char(min(field3), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        ||'-'|| to_char(max(field3), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as field3,
    sum(field4) as field4
from (
    select field1, field2, field3, field4,
        case when field3 between date '2013-02-01'
                and date '2013-02-05' - interval '1' second then 1
            when field3 between date '2013-02-05'
                and date '2013-02-08' - interval '1' second then 2
        end as gr
    from t42
)
group by field1, field2, gr
order by field1, field2, gr;

F     FIELD2 FIELD3                    FIELD4
- ---------- --------------------- ----------
A          1 02/01/2013-02/04/2013         14
A          1 02/05/2013-02/07/2013         21
```

The display of `field3` will look wrong if there is no data for one of the boundary days, but I'm not sure that's the biggest problem with this approach *8-)

You can potentially modify the `case` to have more generic groups, but I'm not sure how this will be used.

Comment: thank you very much . Actually I have been asked to make 2 groups based on date.  they are "October 30, 2011 - January 28, 2012"  AND
"October 28, 2012 - February 2, 2013"   ..

Comment: I ran the query and the GR field is coming as null .. is it unable to recognize '2013-02-05' as DATE?

Comment: I used ANSI date literals, ie `date '2013-02-05'`, which should always be recognised. Your `field3` really is a `DATE` I hope?

Comment: @user1371683 - I also hadn't noticed you had your dates overlapping, which explains the 21/30 discrepancy. This won't work if you really do want overlaps, as only one branch of the case will be used for each row, and you (seem to) want some rows to be counted in each group.

Answer (score 1):

The questions/answers in the comment section to your ariginal answer show that you are actually looking for two different selections - one for the first date range and one for the overlapping second date range. Only you want to get all result records in a single result set. You can use UNION for that:

```
select field1, field2, min(trunc(field3))) || '-' || max(trunc(field3))), sum(field4)
from yourtable
where to_char(field3, 'yyyymmdd') between '20130201' and '20130204'
group by field1, field2
UNION
select field1, field2, min(trunc(field3))) || '-' || max(trunc(field3))), sum(field4)
from yourtable
where to_char(field3, 'yyyymmdd') between '20130203' and '20130207'
group by field1, field2
order by 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you say you specify two groups of dates which do not overlap.  This comntradicts the data you posted in your question.  Several people have wasted their time proposing non-solutions because of your tiresome inability to expalin your requirements in a clear and simple fashion.

Anyway, assuming you have finally got your story straight and the two groups don't overlap this should work for you:

```
with data as (
    select field1
           , field2
           , field4
           , case when field3 between date '2011-10-30' and date '2012-01-28' then 'GR1' 
                  when field3 between date '2012-10-28' and date '2013-02-03' then 'GR2'
                  else null
             end as GRP
    from your_table )
select field1
       , field2
       , GRP
       , sum(field4) as sum_field4
from data
where GRP is not null
order by 1, 2, 3
/
```